# unknown contact force between two links not colliding and not connected in Drake

Tags: drake

As you may see from this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq94Z.jpg)

base_link: is the car frame in light blue
tire_frame: is the black item
front_tire: is the while tire

As you may see, the base_link connects to the tire_frame via a continuous joint and the tire_frame connects to the white tire via another continuous joint.

The ModelVisualizer claims I have two contact forces between the white tires at front and the base_link as shown in two Green lines.

Can people please advise how am I suppose to debug this further? Please feel free to ask if I am not providing enough information for further assistance.

I tried to make the ModelVisualizer renders the proximity models, aka the collision geometry. As you may observed, there is no collision point at all between base_link and the white_front_tire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by slightly change the base_link model, maybe the actual collision geometry isn't the one showing in "proximity"

Comment: It's hard to understand the details from that one image. 

The proximity geometry that is visualized is absolutely the collision geometry.  But if these are mesh files, then by default Drake will take the convex hull of the mesh geometry.  Perhaps that's what is confusing the situation?

Comment: fwiw -- i've opened https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/20618

Comment: ahh, thanks for you comments! This PR looks really close to the problem that I observed. I eventually have to change my 3D model in a certain way to avoid the problem. (Let me know if you are interested in how I resolved the issue, I may need to draw something to explain it).

Comment: I would truly recommend that if the engine/anywhere in the framework turns out to be learning the a geometry shape out of the mesh, the visualization should be definitely show the exact shape of collision. Also, add it to the explanation of the API or some other ways to WARN the user that, hey... I know you gave us the mesh, but we have it calculate geometry shapes out it. Doing this silently can really confuse the API user.